# Auto fill of # style comments in Emacs python-mode not working

Tags: python, fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

My expectation is that, like for comments in other language modes besides python, I could write a long comment, say 150 chars, and it would automatically fill, i.e., newline and indent with comment starting newline, or at least allow me to do `evil-fill` (I use evil-mode) for same, but instead nothing happens. I have to manually format long comment lines that start with `#`.

In a python file, while in python-mode, when I do `M-x auto-fill-mode` it disables auto-fill-mode so I know it is turned on. Initially I thought maybe that was it. `C-h v auto-fill-mode` says its value is `-1`, not sure if that matters (but it did seem weird since a negative value usually means it is turned off - but in this case, since auto-fill works in `"""` comments, I know that can't be the case).

Also, it does auto-fill, as I type, comments in a python docstring `"""` environment.

Perhaps this is default and expected behavior (for most python programmers), I don't know.

Does your Python config auto-fill `#` style comments? Have an idea what to look for to make it do this?

Update: I do find that [filladapt-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt) mostly resolves the issue: (1) It nicely handles filling inside a `"""` style comment, (2) but, while it does fill inside a `#` style comment, it does not automatically start each newline with a `#` character. Not a big deal but something I need to see about enabling.

Update: Actually, I finally found a setup that works great for filling both style python comments. I give the `use-package` config I use to enable it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [filladapt](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt) with the following very simple config worked well to solve the issue I described above:

```
(use-package python
  :after filladapt
  :config
  (filladapt-mode 1))
```

Comment: FYI: You can choose your own answer as the accepted answer.